# Unable to connect to my database image after changing credentials

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I recently finished to build a small Laravel website that has a database, so I created an image of it through docker-compose, and attached a mariadb image to it and provided some credentials. Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env.docker
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '80:80'
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env.mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: $${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 3306
```

Here is the relevant part of my `.env.docker` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=lestadium_db_1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=stadium
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=3p1c_P@ssw0rd
```

and here is the `.env.mysql` file:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=3p1c_P@ssw0rd
MYSQL_DATABASE=stadium
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=3p1c_P@ssw0rd
```

However, I would like to use a user named "stadium" as a user and another password, more secure than this one (even though it's not the one I use), but after changing the credentials, I got the following error from the console:

> 2018-03-31 15:40:03 140076405188352 [Warning] Access denied for user
>   'stadium'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)

And after falling back to "root" and the old password, I got the pretty much same error with "root" instead of "stadium" as user. I found somewhere on a github issue that Mariadb and MySQL tend to create some volumes without asking to persist datas, so I ran `docker-compose rm -v`, it worked, and I should have stopped there, but after changing the user again and re-running the command, it didn't seem to work anymore.

How can I solve this problem?

Any suggestion is welcome